# Getting notifications after log out

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I tested notifications with one account, logged out of it, and created a new account to test the registration process then once I registered with the new account I was able to see the messages from the original account I logged out of in the message history of the new account.

So how can I restrict getting notification in logged out devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by checking from the server side that whether user is logged in or not.

If user is logged in then only send the notification else not.

So at PHP side (server side) , you have to set and get the flag of **"logged in"** using webservice. If user is logged in then send the notification or not. And using webservice , at the mobile app side, you have to set value of **"logged in"** flag on log out.

Hope this will help.

Comment: what happens if user deletes the app ? and try to login again

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER when user logs in again after app has been deleted and reinstalled , new device token/APNS token for that user will be updated on the server